# $F$ is a field, $K$ is the splitting field of all the polynomials over $F$, how to prove that $K$ is an algebraic closure of $F$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

$F$ is a field, $K$ is the splitting field of all the polynomials over $F$, how to prove that $K$ is an algebraic closure of $F$.

I know this result, but I don't know the details of the proof, which is important for me to understand the theory. I'm waiting for your answer, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to show that $ K $ is algebraically closed, which is equivalent to showing that every polynomial in $ K[X] $ has a root in $ K $. Let $ P \in K[X] $ be any polynomial, and let $ L/F $ be the extension obtained by adjoining the coefficients of $ P $ to $ F $. Then, $ L/F $ is a finite extension as the coefficients are in $ K $, which is an algebraic extension of $ F $. Furthermore, let $ \alpha $ be any root of $ P $, then the extension $ L(\alpha)/L $ is finite as $ P $ is the minimal polynomial of $ \alpha $ over $ L $. By the Tower Law, we have that $ [L(\alpha) : F] = [L(\alpha):L] [L:F] $ is finite, which implies that $ \alpha $ is algebraic over $ F $, and it has a minimal polynomial of degree $ \leq [L(\alpha) : F] $. However, this minimal polynomial is in $ F[X] $, and by the conditions imposed, all of its roots lie in $ K $. In particular, $ \alpha \in K $ and $ P $ has a root in $ K $, completing the proof.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer,which helped me a lot .But you skipped  part of the proof:$K/F$ is an algebraic extension,which I guess you take for granted.The following is my proof,if it's wrong or you have a different method ,please tell me.

Comment: Suppose $K=F(X)$,where X is all the roots of polynomials over F[X],$\forall a \in K$ , $\exists a_{0},a_{1},\cdots,a_{n-1}\in X$,s.t. $a\in F(a_{0},a_{1},\cdots,a_{n-1})$,but every $a_{i}$ is a root of some polynomial $P_{i}(x)\in F[x]$,thus $a_{i}$  is algebraic over $F$,consequently ,$F(a_{0},a_{1},\cdots,a_{n-1})$ is a finite extension over $F$.$a$ is algebraic over $F$ since  $a\in F(a_{0},a_{1},\cdots,a_{n-1})$.This completes the proof.

Comment: Any element $ \alpha \in K $ is the root of some polynomial in $ F[X] $ by minimality of the splitting field (if it wasn't, removing it would produce a strictly smaller field in which every polynomial in $ F[X] $ splits, contradicting minimality) and is therefore algebraic over $ F $.

Comment: Get it, your method is simple and much better!

Comment: Emmm, can you explain why $P$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $L$?